# How to check whether a value exists in a array in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is the script i wrote to read each character from a textbox and checking whether that character exists in a array but this isn't working correctly as i'm getting a -1 for any character i enter into the textbox despite of whether its there or not in the array i'm searching that value. Can anyone please help

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var arr1;
    var arr2= $("#myValue").val().split("");

    $("#TextBox1").keyup(function ()
    { 
        arr1 = $("#TextBox1").val().split("");
    });

    $("#btn").click(function ()
    { 
        jQuery.each(arr1, function(i, val)
        {
            $("#xyz").append(this + "<br/>");
            $("#xyz").append(jQuery.inArray(this, arr2)+"<br/>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this running on an ASP.NET page by any chance?

Comment: @ _rusty :  

Yes its running on ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in this line:

```
$("#xyz").append(jQuery.inArray(this, arr2)+"<br/>");
```

change it to:

```
$("#xyz").append(jQuery.inArray(this.toString(), arr2)+"<br/>");
```

because `this` is an object

Comment: thanks bro really helped me i wish i checked this page 38mins ago.. but appreciate your help.

Comment: this is wat i found, perhaps u no this already but wanted to share for someone who might be looking for...

$("#xyz").append(jQuery.inArray(arr1[i], arr2));

Comment: or to make it even easier jQuery.inArray(val, arr2) :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is ASP.NET, have you double checked that `#TextBox1` is the actual final element ID? It might end up be something like `#ctl102_TextBox1`

Comment: yes i did the id is correct, in fact if i change the code to display the items what i'm searching for, its display the correct items. Thanks..!